# How can I sort a list of days of the week according to their calendar occurrence

Tags: c#, android, list

I have a function to sort days according to the week, because they can be not in order, but it's result is not working as expected. What am I doing wrong?

```
        public void SortRemainingDays()
        {
            var listOfTempDays = new List<string>();
            listOfTempDays.Add("Monday");
            listOfTempDays.Add("Tuesday");
            listOfTempDays.Add("Wednesday");
            listOfTempDays.Add("Thursday");
            listOfTempDays.Add("Friday");
            listOfTempDays.Add("Saturday");
            listOfTempDays.Add("Sunday");

            for (int i = 0; i < ListOfRemainingDays.Count; i++)
            {
                var day = ListOfRemainingDays[i];
                listOfTempDays.Remove(day);
            }

            ListOfRemainingDays = listOfTempDays;

        }
```

Comment: `but it's result is not working as expected`  you may want to explain what you expect.  Without it, your  question is "unclear" and will likely be downvoted and closed

Comment: you want to sort days by "Monday", "Tuesday" ... and where you initialized ListOfRemainingDays

Comment: yes, @psubsee2003 you are rite.

Comment: it is clear, its ListofremainingDays is supposed to be sorted like listOfTempDays. Why am I getting downvoted?

Comment: @MikoM You're getting downvotes because the question title is really much too broad, and when it comes to asking why code isn't working, we really do need a full explanation of the **desired behaviour**, the **current behaviour** and what issues you're having.

Comment: I have a static List, which value is defined outside the scope of the function, and it can have values like `{"Monday", "Wednesday", "Tuesday"}`, which are not in order, and I want to sort this List according to the week days, Monday Tuesday Wednesday etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void Main()
{
    SortDaysOfWeek(new[] {
        "Monday",
        "Wednesday",
        "Tuesday",
        "Thursday",
        "Sunday"
    }).Dump();
}

// Define other methods and classes here

DayOfWeek GetDayOfWeekFromString(string str)
{
    return (DayOfWeek)Enum.Parse(typeof(DayOfWeek), str);
}

int GetDayOfWeekPosition(DayOfWeek dow)
{
    return (int)dow;
}

List<string> SortDaysOfWeek(IEnumerable<string> daysOfWeek)
{
    return daysOfWeek
        .Select(GetDayOfWeekFromString)
        .GroupBy(x => GetDayOfWeekPosition(x), x => x)
        .OrderBy(g => g.Key)
        .SelectMany(x => x)
        .Select(dow => dow.ToString())
        .ToList();
}
```

The code above is written for LinqPad (just remove the `Dump()` call).

This assumes you want to sort with Sunday as the first day of the week, that's fairly standard and I'll leave it to you as an exercise to change this if you want Monday to be the first day.

This code produces:

```
1. Sunday
2. Monday
3. Tuesday
4. Wednesday
5. Thursday
```

---

## Update

I've tweaked the code to the following:

```
void Main()
{
    SortDaysOfWeek(new[] {
        "Monday",
        "Wednesday",
        "Tuesday",
        "Thursday",
        "Sunday"
    }).Dump();
}

// Define other methods and classes here

DayOfWeek GetDayOfWeekFromString(string str)
{
    return (DayOfWeek)Enum.Parse(typeof(DayOfWeek), str);
}

int GetDayOfWeekPosition(DayOfWeek dow)
{
    return (int)dow;
}

List<string> SortDaysOfWeek(IEnumerable<string> daysOfWeek)
{
    return daysOfWeek
        .Select(GetDayOfWeekFromString)
        .OrderBy(x => x, new DayOfWeekComparer(false))
        .Select(dow => dow.ToString())
        .ToList();
}

class DayOfWeekComparer : IComparer<DayOfWeek>
{
    private readonly bool _sundayStart = false;
    public DayOfWeekComparer(bool sundayIsStartOfWeek)
    {
        _sundayStart = sundayIsStartOfWeek;
    }
    
    public int Compare(DayOfWeek left, DayOfWeek right)
    {
        var leftPos = (int)left;
        var rightPos = (int)right;
        
        if (!_sundayStart)
        {
            if (left == DayOfWeek.Monday) leftPos = 0;
            if (left == DayOfWeek.Sunday) leftPos = 6;
            if (right == DayOfWeek.Monday) rightPos = 0;
            if (right == DayOfWeek.Sunday) rightPos = 6;
        }
        
        if (leftPos < rightPos) return -1;
        if (leftPos > rightPos) return 1;
        return 0;
    }
}
```

I saw that you'd basically duplicated the `DayOfWeek` enum and used your own positioning, which certainly isn't the way to do this.

Comment: Before I accept this as the answer, can you adjust the code so that Monday is the first day of the week please?

Comment: @MikoM I've left it for you to do, it shouldn't be too difficult, and SO is here to inspire solutions to problems, not be a one stop shop for copy and pasted code. I've shown you the general principle, now it's up to you to adapt it to your needs.

Comment: Oh its just create GetDayOfWeekPosition function?

Answer (score 0):

Code submitted by @Clint works, and to make Monday the first day of the week, I changed the enum values of DayOfWeek.

```
        [Serializable]
        [ComVisible(true)]
        public enum DayOfWeek
        {
            Monday = 0,
            Tuesday = 1,
            Wednesday = 2,
            Thursday = 3,
            Friday = 4,
            Saturday = 5,
            Sunday = 6
        }
```

Comment: see my updated answer, this isn't the way you should be doing this.